# Link local to remote for website

Tags: ftp

I uploaded my first site to my server and noticed a copy mistake. Is there away that allows me to edit the file locally and have it update on my site without having to re-upload the files? For example, my site is saved in a folder on my desktop. I make the changes in Sublime then save them. I then visit my domain to see the changes live.

I'm using Transmit if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use some sort of program or script to accomplish this.  Programs like Dreamweaver can be configured to automatically upload on local save. I'm assuming that sublime should have a plugin you can install to do the same.